# Lock the screen with a popup till the time page gets loaded completely

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

My page takes quite sometime to load a variety of controls and menu images. I want to show a popup window with progress bar on it. The user must not be able to access the original page on the web-browser when this popup is showing.

When the page has loaded completely, this popup must disappear. How to do this?

Comment: Ergh... Do you realise what you're trying to do to your users ?  (humph, sorry, but couldn't resist : I wouldn't come back to a website that does that !)

Comment: What if the connection to a tiny image fails? The whole page would not be usable because of this tiny image.

Comment: Martin, I guess something is foolish on my part. Can you please suggest the best approach?

Comment: First of all, I would suggest optimizing the loading time of your page -- for instance, by reducing the number of external files ;; for more informations, you can take a look at http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/ (there is **much** to read, there ^^ )

Comment: @Martin:

I am using a widget that replaces the TextArea control with a full-fledged Rich Text Editor. When this widget loads, it adds plenty of images on the menu of the TextArea control. How to optimize it? It is a third-party tool.

Comment: Ho ; much harder. Depending on the tool you are using, maybe they have kind of recommendations about performances ? (some do ; some others are especially coded with frontend performance in mind)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be with an overlay -- an absolutely-positioned `<div>` that covers the entire page and has a high `z-index`. Once your page has finished loading (i.e. the `loaded` event fires) then you can remove the `<div>`.

A rough example for styling purposes:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#loading-overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background-color: #000; opacity: 0.7; }
#loading-message { position: absolute; width: 400px; height: 100px; line-height: 100px; background-color: #fff; text-align: center; font-size: 1.2em; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -200px; margin-top: -50px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loading-overlay"></div>
<div id="loading-message">Loading page, please wait...</div>
<!-- rest of page -->
<p>The rest of the page goes here...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Be aware that controls may have their own "loaded" event (e.g. `<img>` tags do), which may fire after the page has completely finished. You would have to experiment to be certain.

Answer (score 2):

This is a custom one I've used on one of my Custom Cloud Applications: 
[NGEN Preload Screen](http://www.vps-net.com/PreloadScreen.html)

View the source for body.onload action...

Feel free to use it at your leisure...

Answer (score 1):

You can have a div that covers the whole screen and in the window.load handler hide that element, but I agree with the comment above. Don't do that to your users.