# Unlock page popup script

Tags: locking

I want to lock a page (e.g:visitors have to complete a contest to unlock page), and when finished paying, they should get redirected to the same original page that was locked.
I saw this: [Lock the screen with a popup till the time page gets loaded completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905779/lock-the-screen-with-a-popup-till-the-time-page-gets-loaded-completely) 
But i want a code that unlocks the same page.
How to unlock page?

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do a ton of work to set this up unless there is a service that does this. You have to build you're own backend using Paypal's seller API and remove the lock using PHP or similar preprocessor. I never like webpages that do this but you're free to do whatever you like.

edit: With a contest you would still have to write the server to interpret answers/some contest information and unlock the portal with a cookie or IP-based. You can't just "get codes" to unlock it. With the code tutorial you found you can probably use jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to remove the element when you're finished.